# Is this a question tag?

Tags: questions, tag-questions

> Roy: “I know it’s tough on you now. But you get through it.”
>  Tom:
>   “**Will I**?”
>  Roy: “Yes.”
>  ([source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/archers): BBC, The Archers,
>   2013-04-26 Friday, 12’03”~12’07”)

Tom takes the Roy’s question tag – “you get through it, **will you**?” and says “will I?”, doesn’t’ he?

Comment: Is it only me or the question is pretty vague at the moment? Can you please elaborate on what you are asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Will I?" is a question. A question tag is the highlighted part in the following sentences.

> He should read this book, **shouldn't he**?

> He reads a lot of books, **doesn't he**?

> This is a book, **isn't it**?

What Roy says is a statement; he is not asking Roy if he will get through it.